# HTML : How to add + symbol after a counter text?

Tags: html, css

Below is the code using [purecounterjs](https://github.com/srexi/purecounterjs). I want to add a "+" symbol after the counter to show that I do not have the exact number. If I add it with span, it goes to next line.

```
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="count-box">
          <i class="bi bi-emoji-smile"></i>
          <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="50" data-purecounter-duration="2" class="purecounter"></span>
          <p>Happy Clients</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mt-5 mt-md-0">
        <div class="count-box">
          <i class="bi bi-journal-richtext"></i>
          <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="10000" data-purecounter-duration="5" class="purecounter"></span>
          <p>Projects Delivered</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mt-5 mt-lg-0">
        <div class="count-box">
          <i class="bi bi-headset"></i>
          <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="30" data-purecounter-duration="1" class="purecounter"></span>
          <p>Years of Experience</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mt-5 mt-lg-0">
        <div class="count-box">
          <i class="bi bi-people"></i>
          <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="40"+ data-purecounter-duration="2" class="purecounter"></span>
          <p>Hardworking Employees</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: _"but if i am adding it witj span it is going to next line"_ - that would probably be due to the styling applied to this then, because otherwise two spans as inline elements should sit next to each other quite fine.

Comment: The issue was in the styles 
.counts .count-box span {
  font-size: 36px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #062b5b;
}
Removing the display: block worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can add the plus in a separate container and force the browser to display them in one line using `flex-wrap: nowrap;`

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@srexi/purecounterjs/dist/purecounter_vanilla.js"></script>


<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap;">
    <span
        data-purecounter-start="0"
        data-purecounter-end="9"
        class="purecounter">0</span>
    <span>+</span>
</div>

<script> new PureCounter();</script>
```

Comment: That adds the symbol at the beginning of the count and adds a decimal value.

Comment: sorry, then I misunderstood your question. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, the above answer in the comment part worked, it was a styling issue